# Socket.io sending to specific client

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

could anybody tell me why I'm getting an undefined response?

It's definitely saving the socket.io socket ID, as I've checked. The typeof the response is "undefined". It's successfully connecting, as I can see it on the server code (main.js), and I can see the uuid as well as the socket id.

main.js

```
'use strict';
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var fs = require('fs');
var fse = require('fs-extra');
var rimraf = require('rimraf');
var socketio = require('socket.io')();

var cnf = require('./config.js');

var myId = uuid.v4();
var connectedWorkers = {};

if (!fs.existsSync('runtime')) {
    console.log("runtime directory cannot be found");
}

rimraf.sync('runtime/generated');
fs.mkdirSync("runtime/generated", function(err){
    if(err){ 
        console.log(err);
        response.send("ERROR! Can't make the directory! \n");    // echo the result back
    }
});

socketio.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('connection!');
    var newId = uuid.v4();
    connectedWorkers[newId] = socket.id;
    socketio.sockets.in(connectedWorkers[newId]).emit("test", {asd:"asdasd"});
    console.dir(connectedWorkers);
});
socketio.listen(3000);
```

client.js

```
'use strict';

var cnf = require('./config.js');

var socket = require('socket.io-client')(cnf.serverURL);

socket.on('connect', function(data){
    console.log(data);
    socket.on('event', function(data){
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

It's simply because you're logging wrong.

```
socket.on('connect', function(data){    // this 'connect' event have no parameter. Just function()
    console.log(data);                  // therefore 'data' here will be 'undefined'
});

socket.on('test', function(data){
    console.log(data);                  // this will return {asd:"asdasd"} as you emitted this.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `emit` directly on your sockets :

```
socketio.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit("test", {asd:"asdasd"});
});
```

Comment: But I'm not sure I've completely understood your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to listen `test` event on the client side:

```
'use strict';

var cnf = require('./config.js');

var socket = require('socket.io-client')(cnf.serverURL);

socket.on('test', function(data){
    console.log(data.asd);  //should print "asdasd"
});
```